# How $\tan{\frac{A}{2}}\tan{\frac{B}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}$,then find $\angle C$

Tags: trigonometry

In $\Delta ABC$, if $$\tan{\dfrac{A}{2}}\tan{\dfrac{B}{2}}=\dfrac{1}{2}\\\sin{\dfrac{A}{2}}\sin{\dfrac{B}{2}}\sin{\dfrac{C}{2}}=\dfrac{1}{10}$$

Find the $\angle C$

My try: since
$$2\sin{\dfrac{A}{2}}\sin{\dfrac{B}{2}}=\cos{\dfrac{A}{2}}\cos{\dfrac{B}{2}}$$
$$\left(\cos{(\dfrac{A-B}{2})}-\cos{(\dfrac{A+B}{2})}\right)\sin{\dfrac{C}{2}}=\dfrac{1}{5}$$
since
$$\cos{(\dfrac{A+B}{2})}=\sin{\dfrac{C}{2}}$$

so
$$\left(\cos{(\dfrac{A-B}{2})}-\sin{\dfrac{C}{2}}\right)\sin{\dfrac{C}{2}}=\dfrac{1}{5}$$
Then I can't go on.

Comment: You start with two equations, but you have three unknowns. You should first find the missing third equation before you can hope solving the problem.

Comment: Hello, can you know$A+B+C=\pi$!

Comment: Yes, this one ! So now you can get rid of one of the variables and proceed further.

Comment: Hint: for $A\le B$
solution is 
$(A,B,C)=\left( \arctan \dfrac{4}{3}; \dfrac{\pi}{2}; \arctan \dfrac{3}{4} \right)$.

Comment: @Oleg567,why? Thank you can post your solution?

Comment: I'll try now to write sketch.

Answer (score 2):

Denote $~~a=\tan\dfrac{A}{2}$, $~~b=\tan\dfrac{B}{2}$ $($let $a\le b$$)$.

$\sin\dfrac{A}{2}\sin\dfrac{B}{2}\sin\dfrac{C}{2}=\dfrac{1}{10}$;

$\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos A}{2}} \cdot \sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos B}{2}} \cdot \sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos C}{2}}  = \dfrac{1}{10}$;

$(1-\cos A) (1-\cos B)(1-\cos C) = \dfrac{2}{25}$;

$(1-\cos A) ~ (1-\cos B) ~ (1+\cos(A+B)) = \dfrac{2}{25}$;

$\dfrac{2a^2}{1+a^2} \cdot \dfrac{2b^2}{1+b^2} \cdot \dfrac{2(1-ab)^2}{(1+a^2)(1+b^2)} = \dfrac{2}{25}$;

$\dfrac{ab|1-ab|}{(1+a^2)(1+b^2)}=\dfrac{1}{10}$.

Now we get system:

$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
ab=\dfrac{1}{2};\\
\dfrac{ab|1-ab|}{(1+a^2)(1+b^2)}=\dfrac{1}{10}.
\end{array}
\right.
$$

$b=\dfrac{1}{2a}$ $\implies$ $\dfrac{a^2}{(1+a^2)(4a^2+1)}=\dfrac{1}{10}$ ;

$4a^4-5a^2+1=0$;

$(2a-1)(2a+1)(a-1)(a+1)=0$.

there are $2$ positive roots for this eq.:

$a=\dfrac{1}{2}$ and $a=1$.

If $a=\dfrac{1}{2}$, then $b=1$, then $A = \arctan\dfrac{4}{3}=\arcsin\dfrac{4}{5}=\arccos\dfrac{3}{5}$, $~B=\pi/2$, $~C=...$;

If $a=1$, then $b=\dfrac{1}{2}$ (simply permutation of $a,b$).

(don't know if this is the simplest way, but at least this is $\approx$ clear :)

---

Finally,

$C=\arctan\dfrac{3}{4}=\arcsin\dfrac{3}{5}=\arccos\dfrac{4}{5} = 0.643501108793...$.

Comment: @china math, I corrected typos now.